# Thanksgiving Latex Package?

Tags: packages

Does anyone know a cute Thanksgiving Latex package? I used to use the halloweenmath package to make cute ghost proof symbols on my homework, but now Halloween is over...

Answer (score 1):

You can draw turkeys using the `tikzducks` package.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[body=pink]
\path[pattern={Dots[distance=4pt]}] \duckpathjacket;
\path (1,0) node[below,font=\sffamily,align=center] {Please become\\ 
a vegetarian!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

But maybe you can listen to the duck, become a vegetarian...